# How the global variable / constants are lazy in swift

Tags: swift, global, lazy-initialization

From the [docs.swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

Global variable

> Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored properties, global constants and variables do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.

Type properties

> Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access.

So I test the lazy-ness of both of them as follows

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation

var s = Date()
struct Sam {
    static let s  = Date()
}


print(Date())

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: { (t) in
    print(Sam.s)
    print(s)
    exit(0)
})

CFRunLoopRun()
```

I did not run it in the playground. A folk from [forums.swift.org](https://forums.swift.org/t/global-variables-are-always-computed-lazily/20231) suggested not to run it from the playground.

So I store it in a file named `main.swift` and then ran it using `swift main.swift`

It output as follows

> 2020-04-16 18:23:48 +0000
>   2020-04-16 18:23:50 +0000
>   2020-04-16 18:23:48 +0000

So type property initializes lazily but the global variable is not initialized lazily. So what does it actually mean the global variable/constant is computed lazily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with the Timer and the run loop and how it can prove the laziness of the instantiated objects?

Comment: accessing the lazy properties a bit later. Then check what value in it actually ? recent value or previous value. Check the first print within the timer, which is type property. From doc type properties are lazy, so whenever first access it will initiate. When i start the timer i printed a date and the type properties date is exactly two second later ( when i access it after 2 second later). Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the forum thread you link the scope of `main.swift` is similar to the scope of a Swift Playground, variables declared at the top level are treated as local variables instead of global variables.

In your example `s` is a local variable, hence it is not lazily initialised.

Create a new file and and only declare `s` there (I changed names to be more clear):

```
// otherFile.swift

import Foundation

let globalS = Date()
```

Then in your main:

```
// main.swift

import Foundation

struct S {
  static let classS = Date()
}

let localS = Date()

print("Reference date:      \(Date())")
sleep(2)
print("Local var s date:    \(localS)")
print("Global var s date:   \(globalS)")
print("Class property date: \(S.classS)")
```

This should print something like:

```
Reference date:      2020-04-16 21:47:47 +0000
Local var s date:    2020-04-16 21:47:47 +0000
Global var s date:   2020-04-16 21:47:49 +0000
Class property date: 2020-04-16 21:47:49 +0000
```

The local var has the same time as the reference time, hence it was initialised eagerly. The static var and the global are two seconds after, proving that they were instantiated lazily, at the time of the call.

This demonstrates the difference between a global variable and a local variable: the top level scope of your main is a local scope as in a function while the top scope in other files are global scopes.